# Is it possible to output different audio to HDMI and built-in speaker simultaneously?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio, hdmi

After I connected my Macbook Pro to an HDTV with HDMI cord, I can choose to output audio to either the HDMI port or the built-in speaker. And I know that it it possible to create a "congregate" audio device so that the same audio can be outputted to both the HDMI port and the built-in speaker.

I would like to know if it is possible to output different audio to the HDMI port and the built-in speaker simultaneously? i.e. Play a movie on the HDTV and play its sound from there, but for everything else play the sound from the built-in speaker.

Thank you.

Hardware: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
OS: OS X El Capitan

Comment: I've never tested SoundFlower for splitting and routing output quite in that way, but this is definitely the first things that comes to mind on what to possibly investigate. https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/

Comment: SoundFlower has been dodgy since Mavericks; I wouldn't trust it any more, unless the v2 currently in beta ever gets to a stable release. Right now it is prone to kernel panics. Beta at https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/ Anything else [Airfoil, Audio Hijack etc] actually made & supported by Rogue Amoeba would be a far better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using AirFoil. I use it on my Mac to send audio out from a specific application to multiple sources (which can include the internal speaker as well as any external audio output device).

My use case though is to allow Spotify to send its audio out to my AirPlay speaker while allowing the internal speakers to still play only system notification sounds.

Check it out here: https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/

(note I do not work for AirFoil, just an awesome product).

Comment: Thanks David, this looks promising. My use case is a tad trickier: the video I'd like to play is actually on Youtube so application-based routing might not be sufficient. That said, I can simply use a different browser alongside Safari to play that Youtube video dedicatedly. I will test it out when I get around to it.

Comment: Ah, yeah, exactly that. Sometimes I have Chrome open to use YouTube with Airfoil while using Safari for normal browsing.

A quick Google Search shows there are actually dedicated apps for OS X for YouTube browsing:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/go-for-youtube/id980327293?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

http://elitebits.com/tubeg/#appDownload

http://mix1009.com/foxtubemac/

http://www.celmaro.com/tubbler/

http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube

I haven't used any of these so can't comment on quality.