# Sending multiple audio streams to different places simultaneously

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Using only built-in macOS functionality, or possibly a Homebrew package, is there any way I can send audio from one music program (eg. iTunes) to a Bluetooth speaker, whilst simultaneously sending the audio from another music program (eg. Spotify) to the local audio device (ie. headphones or a USB-connected sound card)?

Some audio apps have a "Output Audio Device" setting, but neither iTunes nor Spotify has this.

Both a specific solution for the specific case above, and a general approach to sending *n* number of audio streams to *n* number of different audio devices (including Bluetooth) is interesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to output different audio to HDMI and built-in speaker simultaneously?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245413/is-it-possible-to-output-different-audio-to-hdmi-and-built-in-speaker-simultaneo)

Comment: @IconDaemon: Edited. The issue is the same, but I'd like to know if there are free solutions available. Commercial software is a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

You can send one or more audio inputs to one or more outputs by creating a new aggregate device in the Audio Midi Setup app in your Utilities folder. This [Apple Support document](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT202000) explains the steps.

Other options include [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower), the open source virtual audio output device which was maintained by Rogue Amoeba for a while, or [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/), which is Rogue Amoeba's current (non-free) solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think Airfoil from Rogue Amoeba will do what you're asking https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/

Comment: Thanks, but Airfoil costs money, so it's a last resort. I'm first looking for built-in or freeware solutions.

Comment: The value of Rogue Amoeba is very high @forthrin - so hopefully you can budget if you need their software rather than running all your sound through dedicated hardware.